# run 15 to 20 developers on 1 vm server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, virtual-machine

Is it possible to run 15 to 20 developers (VS2010, and other supporting software) off of 1 VM server and is there any documentation to support this?

Comment: Compare the yearly salary of your developers to the potential savings in hardware costs, and you hopefully see that such a structure is not worth the risk of getting your developers ineffective.

Comment: I'm not really looking at hardware savings. The developers run server 03 because of the complicated SOA environment and the network admins don't like that so thier answer is to VM all developers to one box.  --thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible, but you'd need a pretty [beefy server-quality](http://www.vmware.com/support/esx2/doc/intro_sysreqs_esx.html) machine to be the host.  Look into [ESX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX).  Its basically its own operating system that runs a bunch of embedded VMs that you can use Remote Desktop to get in to.

Comment: Do you think it would need 4 processors or 16 needed with 8 virtual CPUs per processor and 64 gigs? It seems crazy to me but I have to spec one out.

Comment: I don't really know the hardware requirments in detail;  I know we use ESX machines for development at work, and they're pretty performant, but they are running on a dedicated farm of 10 or so big servers.  Another department is responsible for the servers, so I don't know much about them.  Maybe post this question on ServerFault?

Comment: I can say, though, that when they had it on a single machine for Proof of Concept, the performance on the machines was terrible, and degraded with each subsequent login.  Became unusable on that single box (of whatever it was) after about 6 users had logged in.